# How to Run the same c program in both windows and linux

Tags: c

I have written a c program in linux environment using linux system call.I want to run that program in windows environment.Is it possible?

If it is possible,then how to do it?

Comment: If you have written a `C` program,then why did you tagged your question as `Ruby on Rails`?

Comment: Can you please show us some code with a minimal working example? Also, it would help if you properly formatted your question.

Comment: "How to run a Linux program in Windows" is not even a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install VMWare Player or VirtualBox in windows.
2. Install Linux in your virtual machine.
3. Run your program on linux in virtual machine.
4. Bazinga. Your linux program runs on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything like using wine on windows. Installing cygwin on the windows machine and recompiling your source code is an option.